# jQuery-Ajax Getting null for xhr.getResponseHeader("Location")

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried above all suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531515/jquery-cors-and-redirects) but getting

> null in xhr.getHeaderResponse('Location'). Following is the quick code view:

```
param.async = true;
param.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };
param.crossDomain = true,
param.processData = false;
param.headers = {
    "content-type":"application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
}

var request = $.ajax(param);

request.done(function( result,status,xhr ){
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Location"));
});
```

However running url and by checking the request parameters, it shows Location in Response headers:

```
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1403
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 23 May 2018 05:23:14 GMT
Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?state=<my state code>&redirect_uri=<my redirect url>&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=<my client id>&scope=<my scope>&access_type=online
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Can anyone please let me know where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with CROS, try the same XHR call with plain JavaScript

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open('GET', "http://example.com/redirect", true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {   
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseURL);   
      }
    };

    xhr.send();
```

Comment: Yes! It worked. Thank you. Now I need to change from jQuery to plain JS.